# Laravel command "__construct" has a parameter but where does it come from?

Tags: laravel-5

The vendor's code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Create a new SendEmailsCommand instance.
 *
 * @param Store $store
 */
public function __construct(Store $store)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->store = $store;
}
```

But when I invoke this command with say `php artisan mail:send`, where does the value of `$store` come from?  Is this what is meant by this cryptic documentation quote?

> Note that we are able to inject any dependencies we need into the
>   command's constructor. The Laravel service container will
>   automatically inject all dependencies type-hinted in the constructor.

I see that Laravel *(5.2)* documentation on console commands seems to do a similar thing with an object called `Drip` ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#command-structure

Is Laravel taking upon itself to realize that there's a type-name given to the constructor, and it automagically instantiates a corresponding object instead of expecting your constructor to do so itself?

Comment: [This](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container) might help you understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, fubar.  My assumptions were correct.